# Node.js Express Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

You can find my entire repo for this project here: https://github.com/austindickey/FriendFinder

Follow the ReadMe to initialize on your computer after downloading the directory.

My survey.html page cannot seem to find the onClick.js file.

Error message -- Failed to load resource: (onClick.js) the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

When I take my code out of the onClick file and put it script tags at the bottom of the survey.html page, I get a different error.

Error message -- ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

I'm completely lost. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to make your question more focused and self-contained. Dumping a project link here is asking for a lot of work.

Comment: The code looks incomplete.  I don't see where the server has any route for `onclick.js`.  So, when the browser finds the `<script>` tag and requests `onclick.js` from your server, your server doesn't recognize that request and sends back a 404.  One would typically use `express.static()` pointed at some sort of `public` directory that contains the public JS files, image files, CSS files, etc... that will be used in your web pages.

Comment: A nodejs server does not serve any files at all by default.  Right now, you have two routes that serve two HTML files, but you have no routes for any of the images or script files used in those HTML files so those other files will not work.  The browser will find their `<script>` or `<img>` tags and ask your server for those resources and your serve will just give it a 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks incomplete. I don't see where the server has any route for `onclick.js`. So, when the browser finds this tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../onClick/onClick.js"></script>
```

and then the browser requests `onclick.js` from your server, your server doesn't recognize that request and sends back a 404.  One would typically use `express.static()` pointed at some sort of public directory that contains the public JS files, image files, CSS files, etc... that will be used in your web pages.   That `express.static()` middleware would look in the public directory of your server file system to see if an incoming request can be found there and if so, it would sent it back to the browser.  It appears you would have the same issue with any images or CSS files you might use in your HTML pages as there are no routes for them either.

Just to recap,  a nodejs server does not serve any files at all by default. Right now, you have two routes that serve two HTML files, but you have no routes for any of the images or script files used in those HTML files so those other files will not work. The browser will find their `<script>` or `<img>` tags and ask your server for those resources and your serve will just give it a 404.   You need routes for those files or some generic `express.static()` middleware that will satisfy the requests for those files.

Also, do NOT use paths like `"../onClick/onClick.js"` for your other resources.  Your are NOT specifying a path to your server file system.  Instead, you're specify a top level URL and your server is then programmed to look in a specific directory on your server's disk to find the matching file.  This URL might be something like `"/scripts/onclick.js"` and then you would configure an `express.static()` route to make sure it works with that URL.